# Bootstrap 4.1.1 CSS carousel slider arrows alignment

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

How can i arrange the carousel control arrows from left and right end of screen in Bootstrap 4.1.1?
I tried following code but didn't work.

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev{
  left: 5px
}
.carousel-control .icon-next{
  right: 5px
}
```

This is my HTML code for the carousal.

```
<div id="slider3" class="carousel slide mb-5 carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-target="#slider3" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#slider3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#slider3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#slider3" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#slider3" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/car1.jpg" alt="First Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/car2.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/car3.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/car2.jpg" alt="Fourth Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/car3.jpg" alt="Fifth Slide">
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- CONTROLS -->
            <a href="#slider3" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#slider3" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a> 
        </div>
```

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: Updated post. Please check.

Comment: make working fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code, your current approach is also not bad but expensive indeed:

```
.carousel-control-next, 
.carousel-control-prev {
    width:20px;
}
```

**Explanation:** You trying adjust inside element of `next prev` buttons. But button is icon container which had `flex` with `align-items:center`, that's why it is not applying your `.carousel-control .icon-prev` positions.